# Laravel Nova installation via composer fails on production server

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-nova

I have added Laravel Nova to our application and purchased a license. On the local server everything works perfectly. However, when I try to deploy the updated application to our linux server and run ***composer update*** it says:

```
Failed to download laravel/nova from dist: /var/www/{myPath} does not exist and could not be created.
    Now trying to download from source

Syncing laravel/nova (3.29.0) into cache

Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new It will be stored in "/var/www/{myPath}"
```

So I created a *GitHub Token* and added the Laravel Nova credentials to the *auth.json* file on the server too. Everything should be correct and it is working on the local copy as I said before. However, I am getting the following errors:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                    
Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@github.com:laravel/nova.git' '/var/www/{myPath}/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-laravel-nova.git/'                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                        
Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/{myPath}/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-laravel-nova.git'...                                     
ERROR: Repository not found.                                                                                                                          
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                        
Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                                   
and the repository exists.
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to run `composer update` during a deployment? That can lead to different libraries being installed on different systems, and that's something you should avoid at all times

Comment: Also, `/var/www/{myPath} does not exist and could not be created` sounds strange - what have you tried to resolve this? Is that path maybe missing, or is it configured with wrong permissions such that your deployment process cannot write into that path?

Comment: @NicoHaase : I know what ```composer update```does. The deployment takes place on our public DevServer. {myPath} is just a placeholder for the real path because of privacy reasons. There is nothing wrong with the configuration. It's all about the Laravel Nova resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the `/vendor` directory and the `composer.lock` file and running `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`solved the problem.

Comment: This is potentially incredibly problematic. The lock file exists for a reason, i.e. to lock versions with known compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and finally figured out the cause and its due to the laravel/nova:3.29. A minor upgrade to 3.30 fixed the issue for me without having to delete the whole composer.lock file as it will update some other packages as well.

Comment: And how did you upgrade? You can't just change the composer.lock file, it will need new hash values & download targets and might have dependencies.

Comment: `composer require "laravel/nova:3.30"`

It will update the composer.lock but not delete it entirely as @arety_ aluded to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create file at root directory with name "auth.json"
2. copy your nova credentials to it

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "nova.laravel.com": {
            "username": "email",
            "password": "passsword"
        }
    }
}
```

3. composer update

Comment: How can these be kept in the environment instead of the source? Seems like a sketchy place to put creds...

Comment: I keep mine in `~/.composer/auth.json` locally on MacOS. That way, the auth works for all projects that use Nova. That is locally.